# How long is SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier?

Tags: unity

How long is `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`?

The [official docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html) say nothing about it. Obviously I can do a few tries, but these will definitely not be conclusive: did someone either gather extensive data, or somehow analyzed the algorytm that creates it?

Comment: I'm curious why this matters? It's a string, so you can get the length of any *particular* invocation easily enough. Are you trying to pre-allocate static storage large enough to hold this for some reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285058/how-can-systeminfo-deviceuniqueidentifier-be-unique

Comment: @JoshPetrie I'm going to put it in a db, so I need to know how big the field is going to be. Since it will be client-provided, and clients can easily cheat, I can't just accept any length, or it would be trivial to saturate my db with fake data… so I would have to put a cap anyway.

Comment: @Byte56 that same link, however claims that sometimes it was just an hash instead… did they make the hash as long as the GUIDs?

Comment: @Lohoris As long as you have 128 bits of a hash, it's probably unique enough right? Think you'll need every character of the hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty here is that `deviceUniqueIdentifier` is implemented in terms of different API calls depending on the underlying OS or hardware. On iOS platforms, it uses [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor). On Windows, it uses the [`AdvertisingId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/windows.system.userprofile.advertisingmanager.advertisingid.aspx). In both cases there are fallbacks that might be used.

The fact that the API calls potentially vary even on the same platforms suggests that no guarantee *can* be provided about the length of the resulting identifier, only it's uniqueness properties; those are the only properties guaranteed by all of the underlying OS calls uses, so those are the only ones the Unity API can guarantee forward.

In practice the identifiers currently appear formatted as GUIDs. You could probably reasonably use that as an upper bound for the column size on your database; for maximal protection you could store then as `nvarchar(max)`, but that's seems *pointlessly wasteful*.

It's possible the output of the APIs involved may change in future revisions of the underlying APIs. You'll want to make sure to check for that somewhere, but you don't need to be overly aggressive about it.